# Profiling for analyzing the low level memory accesses of my program

Tags: memory-management

I have to analyze the memory accesses of several programs. What I am looking for is a profiler that allow me to see which one of my programs is more memory intensive insted of computing intensive. I am very interested in the number of accesses to the L1 data cache, L2, and the main memory.

It needs to be for Linux and if it is possible only with command usage. The programming language is c++. If there is any problem with my question, such as I do not understand what you mean or we need more data please comment below.

Thank you.

**Update with the solution**

I have selected the answer of Crashworks as favourited because is the only one that provided something of what I was looking for. But the question is still open, if you know a better solution please answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Intel hardware, then VTune for Linux is probably the best and most full-featured tool available to you.

Otherwise, you may be obliged to read the performance-counter MSRs directly, using the [perfctr](http://sourceforge.net/projects/perfctr/) library. I haven't any experience with this on Linux myself, but I found a couple of papers that may help you (assuming you are on x86 -- if you're running PPC, please reply and I can provide more detailed answers):
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/login.jsp?url=/iel5/11169/35961/01704008.pdf?temp=x
http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~sb3/files/pmc.pdf

In general these tools can't tell you exactly which lines your cache misses occur on, because they work by polling a counter. What you will need to do is poll the "l1 cache miss" counter at the beginning and end of each function you're interested in to see how many misses occur inside that function, and of course you may do so hierarchically. This can be simplified by *eg* inventing a class that records the start timer on entering scope and computes the delta on leaving scope.

VTune's instrumented mode does this for you automatically across the whole program. The equivalent AMD tool is CodeAnalyst. [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) claims to be an open-source cache profiler, but I've never used it myself.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to determine all accesses to memory, since it doesn't make much sense. An access to memory could be executing next instruction (program resides in memory), or when your program reads or write a variable, so your program is almost accessing memory **all the time**.

What could be more interesting for you could be follow the memory usage of your program (both heap and stack). In this case you can use standard **top** command.

You could also monitor system calls (i.e. to write to disk or to attach/alloc a shared memory segment). In this case you should use **strace** command.

A more complete control to do everything would be debugging your program by means of **gdb** debugger. It lets you control your program such as setting breakpoints to a variable so the program is interrputed whenever it is read or written (maybe this is what you were looking for). On the other hand GDB can be tricky to learn so DDD, which is a gtk graphical frontend will help you starting out with it.

**Update**: What you are looking for is really low level memory access that it is not available at user level (that is the task of the kernel of the operating system). I am not sure if even L1 cache management is handled transparently by CPU and hidden to kernel.
What is clear is that you need to go as down as kernel level, so KDB, explained [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-kdbug/) o KDBG, explained [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/linux-net@vger.rutgers.edu/msg01318.html).

**Update 2**: It seems that Linux kernel does handle CPU cache but only L1 cache. The book [Understanding the Linux Virtual Memory Manager](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0131453483) explais how memory management of Linux kernel works. [This chapter](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=336868&seqNum=9) explains some of the guts of L1 cache handling.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [cachegrind](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#cachegrind) (part of the valgrind suite) may be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something more than the unix command `top` will provide?  This provides cpu usage and memory usage of linux programs in an easy to read presentation format.

If you need something more specific, a profiler perhaps, the software language (java/c++/etc.) will help determine which profiler is best for your situation.